# How do I get jsPDF "loaded" so I can use it if I cannot use import?

Tags: jspdf

I am unable to use an import statement to bring in jsPDF in my use case - making a custom component within a Low Code platform (Retool).

`import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";` gets this error: `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

But I also cannot just go straight to `var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');` as I get a `jsPDF is not a constructor` error. And yes, I have tried `jspdf` and other case versions

I have tried the umd, es and node versions but there is no longer a self-referencing version apparently.

So how do I get jsPDF "loaded" so I can use it if I cannot use import?

Answer (score 2):

This syntax worked:

```js
var { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
var pdf = new jsPDF();
```